# nodejs can't communicate with python via named pipes in my mac pro

Tags: node.js, named-pipes

python can communiate with each other via named pipes in my mac .but when i use nodejs to communicate with python ,it get wrong.
**My python code is:**

```
import socket,os
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_UNIX, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
try:
    os.remove("/tmp/test.sock")
except OSError:
    pass
s.bind("/tmp/test.sock")
s.listen(1)
conn, addr = s.accept()
while 1:
    data = conn.recv(1024)
    if not data: break
    conn.send("server")
conn.close()
```

**`my nodejs code is:`**

```
var net = require('net');
var server = net.createServer(function(stream) {
  stream.on('data', function(c) {
    console.log('data:', c.toString());
  });
  stream.on('end', function() {
    server.close();
  });
});

server.listen('/tmp/test.sock');
var stream = net.connect('/tmp/test.sock');
stream.write('hello');
stream.end();
```

Comment: events.js:141
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

Error: listen EADDRINUSE /tmp/test.sock
    at Object.exports._errnoException (util.js:870:11)
    at exports._exceptionWithHostPort (util.js:893:20)
    at Server._listen2 (net.js:1221:19)
    at listen (net.js:1270:10)
    at Server.listen (net.js:1360:5)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/chen-pc/pipecommunicate.js:12:8)
    at Module._compile (module.js:409:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:416:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:343:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:300:12)

Comment: You should paste the error in your question, not as an (unformatted) comment.

Comment: EADDRINUSE: Your node server is trying to run on a port which is already being used.